# Add data to table using onclick function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table, addition

Here is my Code:

```
<body>
<h2>Add/Update Person Form</h2>
<div id = "data">
    <form id = "person">    
        <br><br>
        Name: <input id = "name" name = "name" type = "text">
        <br><br>
        Gender: <input name = "gender" type = "radio" value = "Male"> Male
                <input name = "gender" type = "radio" value = "Female"> Female
        <br><br>
        Age: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <input id = "age" name = "age" type = "text">
        <br><br>
        City: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<select id = "city" name = "city">
                <option>Lahore</option>
                <option>Islamabad</option>
                <option>Karachi</option>
            </select>
        <br><br>
        <input id = "button" type = "button" value = " Reset " onclick = "ResetForm()">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input id = "button" type = "button" value = " Add " onclick = "AddData()">
        <input id = "button" type = "button" value = " Update ">
    </form>
</div>

<h3>List Of Persons</h3>
<div id = "tab">
        <table id = "list" cellspacing = "0px" cellpadding = "20px" text-align = "center">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>Name</td>
                    <td>Gender</td>
                    <td>Age</td>
                    <td>City</td>
                    <td>Action</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>

            </tbody>
        </table>
</div>
```

Here is the code for JAVASCRIPT:

```
<script>
    function AddData(){
        var x = document.getElementById("age").value;
        var y = document.getElementById("name").value;
        var letters = '/^[a-zA-Z]+$/'; 
        if((parseInt(x)!=(x))&&(y==parseInt(y))){
            alert("Wrong Value Entered");
        }
        else{
            var rows = "";
            var name = document.getElementById("gender").value;
            var gender = document.getElementById("gender").value;
            var age = document.getElementById("age").value;
            var city = document.getElementById("city").value;   

            rows += "<tr><td>" + name + "</td><td>" + gender + "</td><td>" + age + "</td><td>" + city + "</td></tr>";
            $(rows).appendTo("#list tbody");
        }   
    }

    function ResetForm(){
        document.getElementById("person").reset();
    }
</script>
```

Now what I want to do is that there are three buttons in this code. Add, reset, update.
Im working on Add right now Reset works. I've written the above code to add data but when ever I click Add the data is not added to the table body. I am using onclick function to add data. All this work is done on a single HTML page. I think the problem is because of single page but I have to do this on one page. Need help with this.

Comment: just as a side note - the "&nbsp" in your html need to be "&nbsp;" (with a semi-colon at the end)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
function AddData() {
    var x = document.getElementById("age").value;
    var y = document.getElementById("name").value;
    var letters = '/^[a-zA-Z]+$/';
    if ((parseInt(x) != (x)) && (y == parseInt(y))) {
        alert("Wrong Value Entered");
    } else {
        var rows = "";
        var name = "sadcsad";
        var gender = $('input[name="gender"]:checked').val();
        var age = document.getElementById("age").value;
        var city = document.getElementById("city").value;

        rows += "<tr><td>" + name + "</td><td>" + gender + "</td><td>" + age + "</td><td>" + city + "</td></tr>";
        $(rows).appendTo("#list tbody");
    }
}
```

What I corrected:

- to retrieve a `<input>` value you need javascript's `.value` or jQuery's `.val()`
- in your function you were looking for `var gender = document.getElementById("gender").innerHTML;`, but there is no input with that ID, you should use `name`
- Note that you must have unique ID's, so in my fiddle I corrected your buttons to `class="button"` instead.

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AQRL2/)

Solution with plain javascript:

```
function AddData() {
    var x = document.getElementById("age").value;
    var y = document.getElementById("name").value;
    var letters = '/^[a-zA-Z]+$/';
    if ((parseInt(x) != (x)) && (y == parseInt(y))) {
        alert("Wrong Value Entered");
    } else {
        var rows = "";
        var name = "sadcsad";
        var gender = document.querySelector('input[name="gender"]:checked');
        gender = gender ? gender.value : '';
        var age = document.getElementById("age").value;
        var city = document.getElementById("city").value;

        rows += "<td>" + name + "</td><td>" + gender + "</td><td>" + age + "</td><td>" + city + "</td>";
        var tbody = document.querySelector("#list tbody");
        var tr = document.createElement("tr");

        tr.innerHTML = rows;
        tbody.appendChild(tr)

        //
    }
}

function ResetForm() {
    document.getElementById("person").reset();
}
```

### [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/AQRL2/2/)

Comment: OP did use jQuery already... `$(rows).appendTo("#list tbody");`

Comment: Hey I tried this It works on fiddle but not working at my end. Can it be a problem in my css?

Comment: @user2631892, do you get any error in the console? and also: do you have the jQuery library loaded?

Comment: No I have not loaded it. Can I do this without using JQuery?

Comment: @user2631892, sure, but you did already have jQuery in your posted code. 1 minute and I will update.

Comment: Ok I searched that on itnernet and I didnt even knew that Im using Jquery:\

Comment: @user2631892, I added a new code with plain javascript, just in case.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

HTML

```
<body>
<h2>Add/Update Person Form</h2>
<div id = "data">
    <form id = "person">    
        <br><br>
        Name: <input id = "name" name = "name" type = "text">
        <br><br>
        Gender: <input class="gender" name = "gender" type = "radio" value = "Male"> Male
                <input class="gender" name = "gender" type = "radio" value = "Female"> Female
        <br><br>
        Age: &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp <input id = "age" name = "age" type = "text">
        <br><br>
        City: &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp<select id = "city" name = "city">
                <option>Lahore</option>
                <option>Islamabad</option>
                <option>Karachi</option>
            </select>
        <br><br>
        <input id = "button" type = "button" value = " Reset " onclick = "ResetForm()">&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
        <input id = "button" type = "button" value = " Add " onclick = "AddData()">
        <input id = "button" type = "button" value = " Update ">
    </form>
</div>

<h3>List Of Persons</h3>
<div id = "tab">
        <table id = "list" cellspacing = "0px" cellpadding = "20px" text-align = "center">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>Name</td>
                    <td>Gender</td>
                    <td>Age</td>
                    <td>City</td>
                    <td>Action</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>

            </tbody>
        </table>
</div>
```

Script

```
function AddData(){
        var x = document.getElementById("age").value;
        var y = document.getElementById("name").value;
        var letters = '/^[a-zA-Z]+$/'; 
        if((parseInt(x)!=(x))&&(y==parseInt(y))){
            alert("Wrong Value Entered");
        }
        else{
            var rows = "";
            var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
            var gender =document.querySelector('.gender:checked').value;
            var age = document.getElementById("age").value;
            var city = document.getElementById("city").value;   

            rows += "<tr><td>" + name + "</td><td>" + gender + "</td><td>" + age + "</td><td>" + city + "</td></tr>";
            $(rows).appendTo("#list tbody");
        }   
    }

    function ResetForm(){
        document.getElementById("person").reset();
    }
```

[DEMO](http://fiddle.jshell.net/9UV8x/2/)