# How to add data to table on click of button using Javascript

Tags: javascript

```
<html>
<head>

<style type="text/css">

table, th, td {
    position: relative;
   border: 1px solid black;
   width: 40%;
   height:40px;
   top: 5%;
}

</style>


<script type="text/javascript">

function lab() 
{
    var x= document.getElementById('lab').value;
    var rows="";
    rows+= "<tr><td>"+x+"</td></tr>";

}

function inp()
{
    var y= document.getElementById('inp1').value;
}

</script>
    </head>
        <body>
                <button id="lab" onclick="lab()" value="label">Label</button> 

                <button id="inp1" onclick="inp()" value="Input">Input</button> 

                <button id="res" onclick="reset()">reset</button>
            </body>

            <table id="me1">
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tbody></tbody>

            </table>

</html>
```

[image]

I am trying to add the text in the column of the table on the click of the button.

so please help me to add the text written on the button in the column of the table

thank you

Comment: Sorry for so much of explanation stackoverflow is trying to screw me with its pop up msg

Comment: i have headache now sorry bye

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add data to table using onclick function in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20562718/add-data-to-table-using-onclick-function-in-javascript)

Comment: I tried to do but it doesnt work that way because it uses JQuery function appendto() which i am not allowed to have to do with the javascript only

Comment: [mcve], please.  http://jsfiddle.net makes it easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand your requirement completely, but you can use `innerHTML` to wipe out earlier contents and insert new. Or use `appendChild` and `createElement` to make and insert new elements on the go. The example demonstrates both with each button.

```js
function lab() {
  var x = document.getElementById('lab').value;
  var rows = "";
  rows += "<tbody><tr><td>" + x + "</td></tr></tbody>";
  document.getElementById('me1').innerHTML = rows;

}

function inp() {
  var table = document.getElementById('me1');
  var tbody = table.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
  var y = document.getElementById('inp1').value;
  var text = document.createTextNode(y);
  var col = document.createElement('td');
  var row = document.createElement('tr');
  col.appendChild(text);
  row.appendChild(col);
  tbody.appendChild(row);
}
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 40%;
  height: 40px;
  top: 5%;
}
```

```html
<button id="lab" onclick="lab()" value="label">Label</button>

<button id="inp1" onclick="inp()" value="Input">Input</button>

<button id="res" onclick="reset()">reset</button>
</body>

<table id="me1">
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tbody></tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: lets just not merge the two td (column) into one, and how about adding a reset function too ? :)

Comment: @Towkir OP could get around those with a few trial and error I guess :) Lets save some space for learning as well.

Comment: Sounds great, he can take my comment as his assignment I guess :p

Answer (score 0):

I have been also trying out how to input values into HTML table with the click of a button, and I found out this simple way by just using **innerHTML** and the **id of the td tag**. I have reformatted your code, hope this would be useful.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>

<style type="text/css">

table, th, td {
    position: relative;
   border: 1px solid black;
   width: 40%;
   height:40px;
   top: 5%;
}

</style>


<script type="text/javascript">

function lab() 
{
    var x= document.getElementById('lab').value;
    document.getElementById('00').innerHTML=x;

}

function inp()
{
    var y= document.getElementById('inp1').value;
    document.getElementById('01').innerHTML=y;
}

</script>
    </head>
        <body>
                <button id="lab" onclick="lab()" value="label">Label</button> 

                <button id="inp1" onclick="inp()" value="Input">Input</button> 

                <button id="res" onclick="reset()">reset</button>
            </body>

            <table id="me1">
                <tr>
                    <td id='00'></td>
                    <td id='01'></td>
                </tr>
                <tbody></tbody>

            </table>

</html>
```